# How to get a dictionary from a file to average a users input value and then print

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, average

I have a function in my program that is supposed to allow the user to input a name and then display the average times for the name entered. This program uses csv import and to read the file and display the data. The file contains a column of names, then times for each name (marathon runner) in Boston, Chicago, and NY.

```
def racerAvg(times):
    name = input("Please enter racers name: ") 
    for row in times:
        if  name == row['name']:
            r1 = int(row['boston'])
            r2 = int(row['chicago'])
            r3 = int(row['NY'])
            avgTime = sum(times) / len(times)
            print(avgTime)
```

Any help with getting this to work properly would be much appreciated!

This is what I tried but I'm not sure what I need to add to get the avg times from the requested name to be calculated and printed.

```
def racerAvg(times):
    name = input("Please enter racers name: ") 
    for row in times:
        if  name == row['name']:
            r1 = int(row['boston'])
            r2 = int(row['chicago'])
            r3 = int(row['NY'])
            avgTime = sum(times) / len(times)
            print(avgTime)
```

Comment: No need to post your code in duplicate, and a sample of your dictionary would be appreciated. Please edit your question.

Comment: How does your csv file look like?

Comment: You've posted what looks like the same code twice and there's no reference to the CSV file you mention - the code is prompting the user at the command line. Is this the right code?

Answer (score 1):

A dummy `times` example.

Times should be in seconds but for the sake of the example let's use integers.

```py
times = [{"name": "A", "boston": 2, "chicago": 3, "NY": 4}, {"name": "B", "boston": 5, "chicago": 6, "NY": 7}]
```

Updated function :

```py
def racerAvg(times):
    name = input("Please enter racers name: ")
    for row in times:
        if  name == row['name']:
            avgTime = (row["boston"] + row["chicago"] + row["NY"]) / 3
            print(avgTime)
            break
```